# Sum consecutive numbers in array and skipping falsy values JS

Tags: javascript

I have an array of numbers with these values

```
const arr = [NaN, NaN, 1, 2, 3, NaN, NaN, 4, 5, 6, 7, NaN, 8, 9, 10, NaN, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500];
```

How can I sum each of these consecutive values, while skipping the false values (NaN) and use this false value as a separator for sub-sums.

Expected result:

```
const res = [6, 22, 27, 1500]
```

So far i tried implementing reduce() but probably in the wrong way, also regular for loops didn't get the expected results..

Comment: So you don't just want to skip falsy values. You want to use them as separator for sub-sums, right? If so, you need to tell that in your question. Because your question doesn't match at all your example. And this isn't an IQ test: we are not supposed to guess and surmise from your example what is the formula.

Comment: Also, how does classical `for` fail? And `reduce`? If we take those claim at face value, does this mean that you wouldn't accept an answer using `for` or `reduce`? Or do you mean that YOUR `for` and `reduce` attempts failed? And if so, please, show that to us. This is what we need to explain you how to correct that (or just tell "I haven't tried I just want you to do it". It is frown upon, but not forbidden. We don't really care about void "I swear I've tried". We aren't school teachers)

Comment: Thanks for the notes on this issue i have, i'll consider this next time i submit a question :) 
it's just a leet coding challenge that i have struggled with for some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the numbers could add up to 0, you will want to perform an `isNaN` test.

Suggested code:

```js
const arr = [NaN, 1, -1, NaN, 1, 2, 3, NaN, NaN, 4, 5, 6, 7, NaN, 8, 9, 10, NaN, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500];
//                ^^^^^^ added those in the example
const sums = arr.reduce((acc, val, i) => {
    if (!Number.isNaN(val)) {
        if (Number.isFinite(arr[i-1])) val += acc.pop();
        acc.push(val);
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(sums);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way using a condition to skip them falsy values:

```js
const arr = [NaN, NaN, 1, 2, 3, NaN, NaN, 4, 5, 6, 7, NaN, 8, 9, 10, NaN, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500];
const countValid = (arr) => {
    let  total = 0;
    let   result = []
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i]) total+=arr[i]
        else if (total !== 0) {
            result.push(total);
            total = 0;
        }
    }
    if (total !== 0)
      result.push(total)
    return result;
}
console.log(countValid(arr)) // prints expected output [6, 22, 27, 1500]
```

Comment: But what if [1, -1]?

Comment: @trincot OP didn't say his array might have negative values

Comment: OP said they had *numbers*... and those are numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This will also work if a series of numbers between NaN and NaN add up to 0 (provided that there are negatives)

```js
const arr = [NaN, NaN, 1, 2, 3, NaN, NaN, 4, 5, 6, 7, NaN, 8, 9, 10, NaN, 100, 200,NaN,1,-1,NaN, 300, 400, 500];

const result = []
let sum=0;
arr.forEach((num,i)=>{

  if(isNaN(num)) {
        if(!isNaN(arr[i-1])){
        result.push(sum)
        sum=0;
        return;
       }
   return;
 }
sum+=num;
if(i===arr.length-1) result.push(sum)
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -3):

You can try this code:

```
let arr = [NaN, NaN, 1, 2, 3, NaN, NaN, 4, 5, 6, 7, NaN, 8, 9, 10, NaN, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500];
let sum = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(arr[i]) sum += arr[i];
}

console.log(sum); // 1515
```